# Does object size affects performance in unity

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine

i want to ask a question  about the effect of object size object performance. I have made 10 cubes of 100units size and 10 cubes of 1 unit size. Will my fps be lower in the first case.

Comment: The answer to this is very complex. I'll sum it up this way: Typically yes, but only if they are the same distance away from the camera. This is because it's going to be more taxing on the gpu to draw the larger object. Physics can come into play as well, and the larger cubes will definitely be harder on the gpu/cpu.

Comment: I think if all the objects are small including the camera then i think there would be no effect. But if all the all the objects are small but camera is not then there would some change in performance. But i cant imagine what that effect would be.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be making a map try to make the shapes as simple as possible, what I mean is if you have a room, don't put 6 cubes that all connect to form a room, just use a plane and connect it, or make the inside of your cube transparent. This comes very useful if you are building large maps, if you are making something simple, than this won't really make a difference. But I recommend getting in the practice of making everything as simple as possible, so you already have practice when you make a bigger game.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the camera's field of vision actually. The more items visible at a time will demand more from the system. Also, Sizes won't be that much of a trouble in orthographic but in the perspective mode, it will surely hit the system's demand.